# NGINX Multiple angular apps error Unexpected token '<' on page refresh

Tags: angular, nginx

i have problems to deploy in my vps centos 7 server with nginx multiples angular apps, i have a landing site and a dashboard site to manage the info from my main site, my main site is configured as the "root" webpage like [www.mydomain.com/home](http://www.mydomain.com/home) and my dashboard is a secondary site configured like [www.mydomain.com/dashboard/home](http://www.mydomain.com/dashboard/home), i dont have any problem if i reload or do something in my landing site, but i have problems in my dashboard but only when the app navigate to different route, for example my dashboard rute on load goes to /dashboard/login then if i refresh the page works ok, the problem comes when i go to the dashboard panel, i have a main routing page with the template of my dashboard like this: [www.mydomain.com/dashboard/home/panel](http://www.mydomain.com/dashboard/home/panel) "home" is my base routing with the template (sidemenu,navbar,etc), panel is a child route and others are so like /dashboard/home/users etc, if i reload my webpage in any of the child routes like /dashboard/home/panel or dashboard/home/users etc, the page reload with a blank page and in the console i have the error  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'.

my nginx configuration is this:

```html
 server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
         # FIRST WEB APP - runs on mydomain
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/home;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        sendfile on;
        rewrite_log on;
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        gzip on;

         location ~ ^/(assets|bower_components|scripts|styles|views) {
         expires     31d;
         add_header  Cache-Control public;
        }

      # SECOND WEB APP - runs on mydomain/dashboard
       location /dashboard {
       autoindex on;
      index index.html;

      alias /usr/share/nginx/html/dashboard;

      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;


      }


        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

my angular routing is like:

app-routing > root route > login/home > home > home child routes (here's the error shows up).

i have tried a lot of stuff with no luck :/

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
location ^~ /dashboard/ {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
}
root /usr/share/nginx/html/dashboard/;
  }
```

Thanks